# golang on windows: How to build for Linux?

Tags: powershell, go, environment-variables, cross-compiling

How do I compile a go file/project on windows for Linux?

On Linux it should be possible via one-liner:

```
GOOS=windows go build -o filename.exe codefile.go
```

I tried something similar via Powershell, but on my Linux server (Ubuntu 16.04 amd64) only an error appears:

> -bash: ./gotest: cannot execute binary file: Exec format error".

I tried with user Env-vars for `GOOS = linux` and `GOARCH = amd64` and via `set GOOS = linux` in Powershell, but I don't know enough about Powershell - the go build command runs without an error and produces the file.

Can anyone explain the general how-to on windows (10 1709 x64) via Powershell (or cmd) (over VS Code) with go-1.10?

Comment: I tried it, but only $env:GOOS="linux"; go build... works

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Use git bash if you have it installed οn your machine and execute the below command

```
env GOOS=linux go build -o filename
```

You could set the execution operating system for the whole command session through:

```
set GOOS=linux
go build -o filename
```

It worked for me on same Windows 10 version and runs smoothly on Ubuntu 16.04 LTS

Comment: That works, but note that you don't need the `env ` part.

Comment: That's correct. The only reason i am using it that way is not to change permanently my go environment, just temporally for the build.

Comment: Omitting the `env ` part also makes the definition of `GOOS`  _command_-scoped; that is, it is only in effect for the child process invoked - that is a fundamental feature of POSIX-like shells; verify with `FOO=bar date; echo $FOO`.

Comment: Oh i didn't know that it's command-scoped. Thanks for pointed it out!

Comment: That's [defined in the spec](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/utilities/xcu_chap02.html#tag_02_09_01): «A "simple command" is a sequence of *optional variable assignments* and redirections, in any sequence, optionally followed by words and redirections, terminated by a control operator.» (emphasis mine).